# tabview - last visited tab activity

Tags: android

I have a TabActivity with 5 tabs in it and each tab has an activity defined. Irrespective of which ever tab i click, when the tabactivity screen is loaded, it always displays the first tab. Is there a way to get the last tab visited?
thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the tab in a sharedpreference, and then when the activity hosting the tab is shown, set the tab.

```
@Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

    }
```

or this

`tabHost.getCurrentTab()`

store the tab ID or index and then set it using,

```
 tabHost.setCurrentTab(index);
```